# Backpropagation through time

Tags: java, .net, python, f#, neural-network

Does anyone know of a library with a working implementation of backpropagation through time?
Any of Java/Python/C#/VB.NET/F# (preferably the last one) will do!

Comment: I  was looking for something like this a while back, but my search turned up empty. If you do find something, please post it so that I can use it, too

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **backpropagation**? Without a problem statement or definition, it's hard to offer a solution.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey: backpropagation through time is a neural network training strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [this one](http://snarli.sourceforge.net/docs/edu/wlu/cs/levy/SNARLI/BPLayer.html) ? Just a Google search to help...

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're already using some library for BP, it should be (TM) rather straightforward to implement BPTT using BP as a step in the process.

The Wikipedia entry for BPTT [1] includes relevant pseudo code.

My own starting point, about 18 years ago, was "The Truck Backer-Upper: An Example of Self-Learning in Neural Networks" [2].

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time

[2] http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~widrow/papers/c1989thetruck.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I've used [NeuronDotNet](http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/manual/index.html) only for a limited time though.  It allows you to create a feed-forward BackPropagation NN.  I especially liked their use of intuitively named classes.  Good luck!

This is a .net library.

Comment: Thanks but backprop and BPTT are different

Comment: The freehostia.com url is defunct. The latest version of NeuronDotNet, 3.0,  can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/ but beware that this sourceforge project is now _inactive_.  NeuronDotNet remains however a relatively mature framework, hopefully someone will take custody of the project if only in a maintenance mode.

Answer (score 3):

I'm from a Java background but [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) has a .net implementation as well (and is a seriously good framework for NNets, with good time series support)

Can't help with an F# framework, but what domain are you coding for?  If it's finance I'll reassert the "take a look at Encog"

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [pybrain](http://pybrain.org/) would do?  The docstring for its `BackpropTrainer` class suggests that it does backpropagation through time:

```
class BackpropTrainer(Trainer):
    """Trainer that trains the parameters of a module according to a
    supervised dataset (potentially sequential) by backpropagating the errors
    (through time)."""
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experiences with [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) - In my view one of the best and almost certainly the most comprehensive general purpose machine learning libraries around.

You could certainly do BPTT with Weka - you may find a ready made classifier that does what you need but even if not you can just chain a few normal backpropagation units together as per the very good [wikipedia article on BPTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time)

Answer (score 0):

I made backpropagation algorithm in Java quite time ago. I uploaded it into GitHub, maybe you can find it useful: https://github.com/bernii/NeuralNetwokPerceptronKohonen

Let me now if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TensorFlow](http://tensorflow.org)'s `dynamic_rnn()` function ([API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#dynamic_rnn)). TensorFlow's [tutorial on Recurrent Neural Networks](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) will help.

Also, this great [blog post](https://danijar.com/introduction-to-recurrent-networks-in-tensorflow/) provides a nice introduction to predicting sequences using TensorFlow. Here's another [blog post](http://mourafiq.com/2016/05/15/predicting-sequences-using-rnn-in-tensorflow.html) with [some code](https://github.com/mouradmourafiq/tensorflow-lstm-regression/blob/master/lstm.py) to predict a time series.