# Backpropogation Through Time with Snarli

Tags: backpropagation

This question stemmed from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5995485/402887) with a recommendation to use Snarli for Backpropogation Through Time. I tried it out for regular Backpropogation and it works great. However, I'm not sure about backprop through time. With the limited documentation I can't quite tell how to do it. I used BpptUpdate, but I need to set some momentum term for a layer. I'm a little confused by this (which layer to set and how).

Anyway, just looking for a quick response and I understand it is probably a very limited audience who has used Snarli. My next step is to email the author if I don't hear anything and I figured I could post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, maybe this goes without saying, but after emailing the author I came to find that examples are found in the CVS repository (not in the .jar file) or in the snarli-apps compressed files at http://sourceforge.net/projects/snarli/files/snarli/Beta0.21/.

An example for BPTT is found in the Caudill file, the Elman loop is found in elman, etc.